# Cross-Domain work arounds in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

How do I get around cross domain issues using the embedded iframe method? Meaning I have Domain A and Domain B and want to embed Domain A on Domain B to bypass the same origin policy? A detailed example would be great!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: Also, can you describe more specifically what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: So basically I work with an integrated application where the parent frame is on Domain A and the content frame is actually a sub-domain of Domain A (not really Domain B)but hosted on another team's server. The problem with using the document.domain is that there are so many frames in the application that lowering the domain to make the frames communicate breaks a lot of other functionality.

Comment: So the problem I'm facing is when I want to make a call to dispatch an event that resides on the subdomain (communication is lost) . It works in IE but not Chrome where I want to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're describing involves creating a 'helper' HTML file on each domain. When you load Domain A, you also load the helper HTML file on Domain B in an iFrame, which allows you to pass information between the 2.

Check out this post as well about iFrame Proxying

http://www.tomslabs.com/index.php/2012/06/iframes-and-javascript-cross-domain-security/

Be aware of the security implications of doing this as well, perhaps checking in the helper HTML files that the parent iFraming them is in fact your own Domain A/B and not somewhere else.